# robot_pose_ekf installation problem

Tags: navigation, ros-hydro, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
When i tried to install the robot_pose_ekf with this commands:
$ rosdep install robot_pose_ekf
 $ roscd robot_pose_ekf
$ rosmake.

i get this:
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 52 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/lior/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140318-154334

when i go to the library i see only 2 librarys cmake and srv and package.xml file.
what could have gone wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142011/robot_pose_ekf-installation-problem/) by [liorfuks](https://answers.ros.org/users/13561/liorfuks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the hydro release, you should be using catkin for most packages, not rosmake. In particular packages with a package.xml are for catkin, not rosbuild. (rosmake is a command that belongs to rosbuild).

Also, if you are on ubuntu, you don't need to compile the package at all. Rosdep should have installed the package from debians. Just go ahead an use it.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1